# How to invoke event of enter pressed programatically for google.maps.places.SearchBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

Research following example:

[google map with search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

html + javascipt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding-left: 14px;  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
        width: 401px;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
}

    </style>
    <title>Places search box</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

after I input `miamy` I should press 'enter' and after map will focus on another place.

I want press enter programatically on this map.

What should I write in browser console?

### P.S.

I tried this:

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
$("#pac-input").trigger(event);
```

But nothing happens

P.S

Yes I understood that specifically for link provided above it doesn't work because `$("#pac-input")` is empty But I rewrite this code locally and '$("#pac-input")' is not empty but nothing happens

### P.S.

topic related with last comment:

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19135468/2674303)

Comment: Programatically when? On what action?

Comment: I want to write code in browser console

Comment: What code? Explain what you want to achieve and when that should occur.

Comment: code whicj will simulate user behaviour.

Comment: In any time I can execute following in console

Comment: You want to type `13` in your browser console to trigger an `Enter` keydown event on the search input??? I just don't get it. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first trigger `focus` on the input element, then trigger a `keydown` event with code `13` (enter key).

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus');
google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
    keyCode: 13
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/1svw299r/)</kbd>

Any issues with this, please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28062160/1238965