# Ignore blur event if user choose address on google map autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using google map API V3 with places and autocomplete API and I have a problem with event order.

I have an input text and when I enter an address in this field I have the autocomplete then I can choose the address with my mouse. It works perfectly.

But if the user type the address without choose the address inside the autocomplete suggestion, the `place_changed`isn't triggered and I can't get the google map object to split the address in the different part (postal_code, city, street_numer...).

So I thought about a solution. I decided to use the `blur` event. In this event I'll use the geocoder to retrieve the address if the user type an ambiguous address or if the user doesn't have click on the autocomplete suggestions. Then I can get the postal_code, street_number... Even the use type an ambiguous address.

I want to use the `blur` event only if the user doesn't click on the autocomplete suggestion. But the problem is that the blur event is trigged before the google map autocomplete event then I can't set a flag variable.

I have to do that because when I'm choosing an address inside the autocomplete suggestion the blur event is triggered and sometimes I have the address of the suggestion and sometimes I have the result of the geocoder.

Here is a part of my code :

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    initializeAddress(place);
});

function geocoder(ambiguousAddress){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({"address": ambiguousAddress}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
            initializeAddress(results[0]);
        }
    });
}

function initializeAddress(place){
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

        latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

        switch (addressType) {
            case 'street_number':
                street_number = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                break;
            case 'route':
                route = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                break;
            case 'locality':
                city = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                break;
            case 'postal_code':
                postal_code = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    address = street_number + ' ' + route;
}

$('#address').on('blur', function(e) {
    if( $.trim($(this).val()) != '' ){
        geocoder($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar issue.  [As per the API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MVCObject), if the user doesn't select anything from the dropdown, getPlace returns a stub with only the input value as place.name.  Geocoding place.name if address components are undefined solves a number of scenarios *except* for tabbing out.  For that, I used the solution from this answer: [Google Autocomplete Places API not triggering event on change via TAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058833/google-autocomplete-places-api-not-triggering-event-on-change-via-tab).

IMHO, this seems harder than it ought to be.

```
function onPlaceChange() {

    console.log("on place change");
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (typeof place.address_components !== "undefined") {
        console.log("place filled in");
        fillInAddress(place);
    } else {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var onSuccess = function (google_results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                fillInAddress(google_results[0]);
            }
        }
        console.log("geocoding " + place.name);
        geocoder.geocode({'address': place.name}, onSuccess);
    }

}

function initAutocomplete() {

    var location_field = document.getElementById('address');
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(location_field, 'blur', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'focus');
        google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'keydown', {
            keyCode: 13
        });
    })

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(location_field),
        {types: ['address']});

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42101702/2409212

Basically what it does it to check if there is a `pac-item` (the class name for every result row) element hovered. If no element is hovered, means that the autoselect should be performed, otherwise, it will let us pick one!

Answer (score -1):

`Autocomplete` class is bound to the textbox. If this is the case, I believe it already has a blur implementation (which is why its being triggered).

Check if you can register `blur` on the `Autocomplete`'s [listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MVCObject). Hopefully this would solve the issue.

Happy coding!